# Sort a list of objects by using their attributes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, idioms

I have a list of `Fruit` structs called `basket`. Each `Fruit` struct has a `name` (a string) and a `calories` (an integer). I would like to sort `basket` so that:

1. The `Fruit`s with the highest `calories` appear first. For example, a fruit with 500 calories appears before a fruit with 400 calories.
2. If two `Fruit`s have equal `calories`, the `Fruit` whose `name` comes first alphabetically comes first, ignoring case. For example, given two fruits with equal calories, one named "banana" will come before one named "Citrus".

The definition of `Fruit` is not something I control so I'd prefer a solution which doesn't involve mixing anything into `Fruit` or changing it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easy solution is

```
basket.sort_by { |f| [-f.calories, f.name] }
```

Of course, if this is *the* canonical sort order for fruit then it *should* be defined using the `<=>` method and with the `Comparable` module mixed into `Fruit`

Comment: Does this take the fact that f.name should be compared case-insensitively into account?

Comment: to do case ignore, swap in f.name.downcase

Comment: This plus a f.name.downcase was exactly what I needed. Thanks! (No, there isn't a defined canonical sort order for fruit; it just so happens that this is how it needs to be sorted in this particular case.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your basket is an Array or a subclass thereof.

### The Fast Way

[Enumerable.sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003151)

As [Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31582/gareth) pointed out, Enumerable (included by Array) has a sort_by method that runs through each list item once.  This is faster to run and faster to write once you get the hang of it.

```
# -f.calories to sort descending
# name.downcase to do a case-insensitive sort
basket = basket.sort_by { |f| [-f.calories, f.name.downcase] }
```

### The Perl Way

[Array.sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002208)

Coming from a Perl background, my first impulse is to grab the spaceship operator <=>.  Cheeky little devil.  Array has the sort and sort! methods that make it very useful.  This solution is slower, and because it's longer it is more likely to introduce bugs.  The only reason to use it is if you're dealing with people unfamiliar with Ruby and unwilling to find the **right** way on StackOverflow.

```
baseket.sort! { |a,b|
  if a.calories == b.calories
    a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase
  else
    # Reverse the result to sort highest first.
    -(a.calories <=> b.calories)
  end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See `Array#sort` ([API doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002208)). You can pass in a block that returns -1, 0, or 1 given two `Fruit` objects, and your block can determine these values using whatever attributes you please.

Comment: The problem with 'sort' is that it re-evaluates the block multiple times, for each pair of items that are compared. using 'sort_by' calculates the comparison key *once* for each item and sorts those

Comment: ..although having said that, it's unlikely to be an issue in this case, as this example won't be using a slow calculation. But still, I think that sort_by is generally a more scalable solution

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sort Fruits a lot, you should probably do a little more work up front and make your objects comparable.

For this, you need to implment the Spaceship-Operator (`<=>`) and include Comparable.

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :name, :color

  def <=>(other)
    # use Array#<=> to compare the attributes
    [self.name.downcase, self.color] <=> [other.name.downcase, other.color]
  end

  include Comparable
end
```

then you can simply do:

```
list_of_fruits.sort
```

Comparable also gives you many other methods (`==`, `<`, `>`) for free, so you can do things like  `if (apple < banana)` (see [the documentation for the Comparable Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html) for more info)

<=>, is specified to return `-1` if `self` is smaller than `other`, `+1` if `other` is smaller and `0` if both objects are equal.