# Can't properly order alphabetically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in the controller:

```
@players = Player.all.order(:last_name).group_by{|player| player.last_name[0]}
```

And in the view I have:

```
- @players.each do |letter, players|

  %h2= letter

  - players.each do |player|
```

This results in the players being *grouped* alphabetically, but they are not *ordered* alphabetically within those groups, e.g:

- Almunia
- Adams
- Angha
- etc

In other words, Adams should come before Almunia of course.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852705/sort-a-list-of-objects-by-using-their-attributes-in-ruby) question has an appropriate/similar answer.

Comment: I'm not really getting an answer from that thread. Maybe I'm not reading it right, but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with sorting by aa > aab > ab > ac > aca, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A little surprising, but I'm not sure `group_by` guarantees the order of elements once grouped.  Fix would be to adjust your `players.each` loop to something like `players.sort_by(&:last_name).each`

Comment: That results in:

    undefined method `last_name' for #<Array:0x007f9f2d037040>

Comment: `- players.each do |player|` -> `- players.sort_by(&:last_name).each do |player|` The second each loop, not the first.

Comment: That results in no difference, players still jumbled around.

Comment: Going to need to see the updated code and a few more lines, maybe the source data and the output itself.

Comment: But wait, let's start here: would sort_by(&:whatever) actually sort alphabetically, i.e:

- aaa
- aba
- abc
- acc
- ada

...? I see no reference to sort_by working like that in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does. https://gist.github.com/phallstrom/d7b69edecc7d9e00a3b14d29ce9cba32

Comment: I'm definitely stuck then. There is no default sorting overriding the local sorting. The only thing I can think of is that it doesn't work when grouping?